# addthis share facebook and google+ url

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-plus, addthis

I am attempting to use AddThis to create simple URL shares for whichever current page the user is on when they click the share button. As of right now, I have Twitter working. When the user clicks, they are able to see the URL populated in the tweet box. Now when the user clicks Facebook or Google+, the URL doesn't seem to show up in the share box.

```
<ul class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <li><a class="addthis_button_facebook"><img src="/img/facebook-social.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="Share" /></a></li>
    <li><a class="addthis_button_twitter"><img src="/img/twitter-social.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="Share" /></a></li>
    <li><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"><img src="/img/google-social.png" width="20" height="20" border="0" alt="Share" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

I feel like I might be missing some Facebook or Google+ parameters. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you specifying the URL to be populated?

Comment: I am building a template page for an article in a blog so the url will be different for each page. The documentation says to use addthis:url="THE URL" but that doesnt work in my case as the url will be different for each article page.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're trying to integrate in your local development environment and your URL is something like localhost:8080. It looks like Google Plus and Facebook invalidate localhost. So its not that they G+ and Facebook don't work, they're just invalidating the URL. If you hard code the URL to be something else, for example www.example.com, both Facebook and Google Plus should work correctly.

A tutorial on how to specify the URL is available at http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381242-url-title

Answer (score 0):

I have test this and this works

check it out on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urmwF/100/)

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox" addthis:url="http://example.com/blog/post/2009/05/01" addthis:title="Hooray!">
<ul class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<li><a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a></li>
<li><a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a></li>
<li><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works if I needed it for a specific page with a specific url. I am creating a template for a blog which will render different urls for each article page. So I need to dynamically set the url specific to the current page.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/125634-setting-the-url-to-share), it also says you can use JavaScript.

Therefore, you can use  [document.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.URL), like so:

```
var addthis_share = {
    url: document.URL
};
```